# How many points does a player Peg if they play three of the same cards consecutively, when the other player is out of cards in cribbage?

Tags: cribbage

Player one is out of cards, and player two is starting from 0. Player two lays down three kings in a row. How many points should be pegged? Should it be 2 for the first pair, plus 6 for the royale pair, and then one for last card with a total of 9? Or just 7?

Answer (score 2):

Play king: "ten"
Play king: "twenty for two": peg two
Play king: "thirty for six": peg six
Peg one for last.

The player who plays the three kings will score a total of 9 points for that sequence.